# Project retirement or archiving

Tags: project-management

What is the best way to retire a currently active project? I've been working on this one for a while now and I think its time to let go. Without going into too much detail, there are other projects and technologies that are way ahead now and I don't see much value in investing in it any further.

What have you done to retire a project and what is the process like?

Comment: Is this something that used to be publicly available or is it something that you've kept for your organization or yourself?

Comment: Yes, tell us more about the context.  Who owns it?  Who uses it?  How is it currently distributed?  

Also, what answers are you looking for? How to convince people to accept the death of the project?  Or what technology to archive things with?  Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As operating systems, compilers, etc. change, it can be difficult to rebuild old projects.

Consider creating a virtual machine that is configured to build it again, in case you need to update it for some reason in the future.  Archive that VM along with the source code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've done this before, and put up on the homepage of the project

"I no longer wish to maintain this project - if you're interested in taking it over, then feel free to email me (email@address)"

And then let someone take it over.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a personal, community, or commercial/professional project?

I have had a professional prject go sour due to lack of feedback form the client. Bascially they were going at a slower pace than they should have and it got to a point where the software would be more expensive to contine than to get a prebuilt alternative. In that case i just brought in the data to show the client where their saving are and recommend to abondon. Its hard to swallow, but after a while they realize it was for the best.